# math operations always returns 0 c#

Tags: c#

I have c# program that calculates percentage and returns int value, but it always returns 0.

I have been writing code for 16 constitutive hours so I appreciate if you find the mistakes within it.

I debugged my code and I found that the value is being passed correctly.

```
private int returnFlag(int carCapacity, int subscribers)
{
    int percentage = (subscribers / carCapacity)*100;
    return percentage;
}
```

Comment: I am passing 5 and 14 so at least it should return something meaningful

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing is the result of operating on two integers, and losing the fractional portion.

This piece of code, when using the values 5 and 14, will truncate to 0:

```
(subscribers / carCapacity)
```

You need to cast one of the operands to a double or decimal:

```
private int returnFlag(int carCapacity, int subscribers)
{
    decimal percentage = ((decimal)subscribers / carCapacity) * 100;

    return (int)percentage;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that since you're performing math on `int` (read: *integer*) values, any fractions or remainders get thrown out. This can be seen by changing your code to

```
int percentage = (subscribers / carCapacity);
percentage *= 100;
```

Since `(subscribers / carCapacity)` results in less than one, the only possible number an `int` can hold is `0` - and `0 * 100` is `0`.

You can fix this by converting to a more precise number, such as `double`, before performing operations:

```
private int returnFlag(int carCapacity, int subscribers)
{
    double percentage = ((double)subscribers / (double)carCapacity) * 100.0;
    return (int)percentage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer types (int) don't work with fractions.  Change the types you are working with in your division to decimal, double, single, or float.